# Get Id of selected td in tr with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the Id of the `td` selected with jquery.

```js
$("#ex_rev").find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
  if (i > 0) {

    var $tds = $(this).find('td');

    var value_of_id = ($tds).attr('id');


    year = $tds.eq(0).text();
    value1 = $tds.eq(1).find("input").val();
    value2 = $tds.eq(2).find("input").val();
    value3 = $tds.eq(3).find("input").val();
    value4 = $tds.eq(4).find("input").val();
    value5 = $tds.eq(5).find("input").val();
    value6 = $tds.eq(6).find("input").val();
    value7 = $tds.eq(7).find("input").val();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td id="ProfessionMedicale" style="font-size:12px" class="details-text-style2">@(_Exercice.n - 1)</td>
  <td style="font-size:12px">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResComptaConvNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
    <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.ResComptaConvNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResComptaConvNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CotisSocNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
    <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.CotisSocNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CotisSocNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
  </td>
  <td style="font-size:12px">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResComptaNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
    <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.ResComptaNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResComptaNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
  </td>


  <td>
    <i class="material-icons ripple" onclick="showRevenu (1)" title="Modifier">edit</i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So here what I want is to get **`id="ProfessionMedicale"`** in **`var value_of_id`** and **$tds** is the first td selected.

In `value_of_id` I didn't get (`id="ProfessionMedicale"`).

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @SystemGlitch in value_of_id i didn't get (id="ProfessionMedicale")

Comment: first of your missing something here `($tds).attr('id');` like either the `$` at the start `$($tds).attr('id');` or `$tds.first().attr('id');`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you it is working now !

Comment: You can also use $("td").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);  
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the ID, then change `var value_of_id = ($tds).attr('id');` to `var value_of_id = $tds.first().attr('id');`

```
var value_of_id = ($tds).attr('id');
                  ^
                  Is missing an $
```

Also it would be better to just use `$tds.first()` to get the first `td` element

**Working Demo**

```js
$("#ex_rev").find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td');
  var value_of_id = $tds.first().attr('id');
  console.log(value_of_id)
  year = $tds.eq(0).text();
  value1 = $tds.eq(1).find("input").val();
  value2 = $tds.eq(2).find("input").val();
  value3 = $tds.eq(3).find("input").val();
  value4 = $tds.eq(4).find("input").val();
  value5 = $tds.eq(5).find("input").val();
  value6 = $tds.eq(6).find("input").val();
  value7 = $tds.eq(7).find("input").val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ex_rev">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="ProfessionMedicale" style="font-size:12px" class="details-text-style2">@(_Exercice.n - 1)</td>
      <td style="font-size:12px">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResComptaConvNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
        <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.ResComptaConvNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResComptaConvNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:12px">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CotisSocNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
        <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.CotisSocNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CotisSocNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:12px">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ResComptaNm1, new { @id = "app_exercice_details_inputs_index_1", @Style = "border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;display:none;width:70px;", @class = "number" })
        <label id="app_exercice_details_span_index_1">@(TnsHelper.FormatDecimal(Model.ResComptaNm1.ToString()))</label> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResComptaNm1, new { @class = "ex_rev" })
      </td>


      <td>
        <i class="material-icons ripple" onclick="showRevenu (1)" title="Modifier">edit</i>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So here what i want is to get id="ProfessionMedicale" in var value_of_id and $tds is **the first td selected**.

The selector `.find('td')` you're using will return all the td's of the row when you need just the first one.

You could to use `:first` selector or the jQuery method `.first()` like:

```
$(this).find('td:first').prop('id');
$(this).find('td').first().prop('id');
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$("#ex_rev").find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
  if (i > 0) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td:first');
    var value_of_id = $tds.attr('id');

    console.log(value_of_id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ex_rev" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>FIRST TH</th>
    <th>SECOND TH</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="ProfessionMedicale" style="font-size:12px" class="details-text-style2">FIRST TD</td>
    <td style="font-size:12px">SECOND TD
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```